# My site loads slowly and the elements look messy

Tags: wordpress, performance, caching, optimization

community!

I have a small problem with the loading of my website done in Wordpress.

When I enter the site, all the elements are displayed in a disorderly way for about 3 or 4 seconds.

After that short time, all the elements are loaded and sorted correctly.

I have tried to use plugins to optimize the load, clear cache and minimize css and javascript. However, the problem continues.

What action can I take on the site to fix this faulty and slow load? Thank you very much.

This is my site: https://www.tecnobreak.com/

Various plugins such as WP-Rocket and WP-Optimize.

Comment: It is a lot of work to ask someone to inspect your site as a whole. Couldn't you reproduce your problem on a smaller test case?

Comment: Of course I do. I don't want my site inspected either. Just some suggestions as to the loading time and mainly why the elements load in such a tidy way. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a loading screen. This will be the easiest route.

Alternatively you will need to priorities what needs to be loaded first on page load.

I assume you have optimized your images and made sure everything is up to date.